# Which version of PHP shall I start learning as a newbie?

Tags: php, mysql

I am willing to learn PHP and MySQL, and I have good knowledge of HTML and CSS. So I decided to purchase a book on PHP for self-study. Recently I ordered an book with title - beginning PHP-6, MySql & blah.. blah.. and the books covers on PHP-6. But I came to know the latest version of PHP is PHP-5.5.8, so how this book is teaching PHP-6. Someone please suggest shall I learn PHP-6 or any other version of PHP for best advantage because I don't want myself ending with depreciated php syntax.

Here is the FlipKart URL selling the book on PHP6 - http://www.flipkart.com/beginning-php6-apache-mysql-web-development/p/itmdytmw6yzujfdz?pid=9788126521227

Comment: The latest version of PHP is 5.5.8, and there is currently no PHP 6. Maybe your book comes from the future ... could you provide something like an Amazon link so we can see it ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be awful if programming languages were like stepping stones? Start with version 1 to learn the basics.. move to version 2 for basic OOP support. version 3 adds dynamic prototyping.. etc etc.

Comment: Buy (or borrow) a book for PHP 5.5.8, and check the index to make sure it covers mysql and PREPARED STATEMENTS

Comment: [http://www.w3schools.com]

Comment: PHP 6 doesn’t exist. You can also read the PHP manual at php.net.

Comment: @AravindKishore `w3schools` shouldn't be recommended to someone starting out. It contains very bad examples, with many security issues - especially when it comes to user input.

Answer (score 3):

You should be learning PHP 5.x (preferably 5.4 at the very latest, but 5.5 if possible).

PHP 6 was never released. The project was abandoned a long time ago, and work continued on the PHP 5.x branch instead.

If you're reading a book about PHP 6, then the book is (a) badly out of date, and (b) contains stuff that is incorrect.

(there's nothing to stop the PHP team releasing a future version under the name PHP 6 if they want to, but if they do it will not be the same as the project that was previously worked on under that name)

Answer (score 0):

PHP 6 does not exist yet. The development of PHP 6 has been stopped and is not scheduled for any time soon.

You can start learning using the latest version, the basic principles are not changing in the 5.x branch, then you will be able to use the future versions without any trouble.